# jrebel standalone could not find agent library in macos

Tags: spring, jrebel, bootrun

i'm running gradle task at project root directory but it erros, looks as below:

> $> ./gradlew bootRun
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not find agent
>   library /Users/xxx/bin/jrebel/libjrebel64.dylib in absolute path, with
>   error: dlopen(/Users/xxx/bin/jrebel/libjrebel64.dylib, 1): image not
>   found

it setup jrebel follow https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/standalone/springboot.html#spring-boot-using-gradle

And, i checked `agentpath` and is right.

Anyone had same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a blank space in your username? I would try to redownload the JRebel again, unzip it into some other folder and then try again.

Comment: There's no blank space in my username.

Comment: Did you try to redownload it and place it in some different place? If so and the problem still persists, please reach out to the JRebel support https://www.jrebel.com/support